# Type React component with ref? Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

So I have a ref:

```
someComponent;
```

And the `someComponent` is basically a React component that looks like:

```
class SomeComponent<IProps> {
   getData = () => {};

   render() {
      ...some stuff
   }
}
```

So, how can I type `someComponent` so if I do:

```
this.someComponent.getData();
```

The `TypeScript` won't shout that `getData` doesn't exist on `this.someComponent`?

I tried:

`someComponent: React.RefObject<SomeComponent<IProps>>`

But TypeScript still warns me.

**Edit**: Tried with createRef, however getting following error:
[image]

Comment: in order to use getData outside that component, you need to pass it as prop

Comment: Where is your ref? Do you mean ref as the react concept, or as the general concept of reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the type of the component when you declare the ref in the parent component:

```js
someComponent = React.createRef<SomeComponent>();
```

And pass the ref to the rendered component:

```js
<SomeComponent ref={this.someComponent} />
```

Then you can call getData like this:

```js
if (this.someComponent.current !== null) {
  this.someComponent.current.getData()
}
```

Comment: I've created a code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-esc1r?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Thank you, however it really doesnt let me to use `SomeComponent` as a type. Check my edit. Whats going on?

Comment: Odd, could you share a repro on code sandbox? Maybe try `createRef<typeof SomeComponent>`, although it shouldn't be necessary in this case.

Comment: Ok Anthony, the problem was the SomeComponent was connected with redux and the ref was forwared. However I decided to disconnect that component from store and it seems to work properly now. Thanks